# How to validate AWS lambda and glue job status programatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am looking for suggestions on how to validate the glue job and lambda function status, like succeeded or failed in the last run, programmatically using BOTO3 Python. We have 10+ lambda function and glue jobs that run once a day; how can this be achieved using the Python script? Any lead would be highly appreciated.

I thought of using cloud watch logs to trigger the alert, but I have been tasked with doing this programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Glue you would need to first loop over all of the Job Runs by calling `GetJobRuns` and parse out which ones you want to know more info about, then call `GetJobRun`:

1. [get_job_runs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_job_runs) | Obtain `JobName` and `RunId` to pass to next API call
2. [get_job_run](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_job_run) | Check status of `JobRunState`

The same thing goes of Lambda, first call `ListFunctions` then call `GetFunction`.

However, I would strongly advise you to use a DynamoDB table to record the status of all your runs. When your Glue or Lambda runs complete, create an item for each run with the status of the job. Then all you need to do is get that days data from DynamoDB.